# Tunnelling VPN through SSH mac

Tags: ssh, vpn, ssh-tunneling, pptp

I have a pptp VPN server set up on my Raspberry Pi at home, and it works really well, except when I'm stuck behind my college's firewall. I can SSH into it through commonly open firewall ports (443, 8080), but I was wondering if I could do the same with VPN.

The way I see it is it should work, since there are 4 ports that I know of open that I can SSH to my Raspberry Pi through (Not port 22 however!), but VPN just won't work. I have tried tinkering for the last two hours, but no luck. Has anyone done something like this before?

Comment: what have you tried so far (please include in your question)? i assume you've tried ssh tunneling and vpn from there?

Comment: I have tried commands like this on my local machine (my mac): ssh -N -p 443 user@domain.com -L 1723/localhost/8080. I wasn't sure but I figured this would take direct my VPN connection attempts from 1723 to 8080. I also had the 'local IP' in my ssh prefs on my Raspberry Pi set to 10.0.1.3 8080

Comment: you need to use the `-w` to specify a tunnel interface instead of creating a forward tunnel. take a look at https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/VPN_over_SSH also take a look at https://github.com/apenwarr/sshuttle/

Comment: Thanks, I have been using sshuttle for the time being, I just wanted to be able to flick the VPN switch and have it turn on as if it weren't behind a firewall at all

Answer (score 2):

You can use `-w` key with ssh.
An example:

```
# ssh root@ssh-server -w 0:0 "/sbin/ifconfig tun0 192.168.100.1/24 pointopoint 192.168.100.2"
# ifconfig tun0 192.168.100.2/24 pointopoint 192.168.100.1
# route add -host ssh-server dev eth0
# route del default
# route add default gw 192.168.100.1
```

But you need connect with root privileges to your ssh-server and tune iptables for NATing your traffic. Don't forget to turn on `PermitTunnel point-to-point` in your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` onto ssh-server

Answer (score 0):

pptp is limited to port 1194 i had a similar problem not so long time ago. You can use another VPN technology than pptp.
Look that :

In .ssh/config :

host raspberrypi.machine
hostname Your_Ip
localforward 1194 Your_Ip:1194

then ssh to raspberrypi.machine

Connect your pptp client to localhost 1194 and it should work.